# Creating a newline in rich text box

Tags: c#, checkbox, richtextbox

I need help on creating a new line for my RichTextBox which I cant make work when using CheckBox.

It keeps overlapping instead of creating a newline of words.

Tried using the method of `rtbdisplay.text = (display+envrionment.newline);`
example from my code:

```
if (rbtnSmall.Checked == true)
{
    rtbDisplay.Text = "displaytext".PadRight(20) + "size".PadRight(23) +
                      qty.ToString().PadRight(20) + StrongDummy;
}
```

Comment: So if you add `+ "\r\n"` right after `StrongDummy` that doesn't work?

Comment: you used WPf or winforms

Comment: it can display in richtextbox but what i wanted was if i click the calculate button again it adds a new line instead of overlapping

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `RichTextBox.Text` property or the `RichtTextBox.AppendText` method to append a string with a newline.

```
myRichTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "My new line.";

// Or

myRichTextBox.AppendText( Environment.NewLine + "My new line." );
```

Comment: what if I wan to display the new line with my variable instead of "my new line" . i tried using my variable switching it with "my newline" still same problem

Comment: Worth noting: Even if you append Environment.NewLine, in RTF, only the \n is retained. If you look at the Text property, you will see that the \r is gone.

Comment: Recently encountered this causing issues because the length of my input string and the `Environment.NewLine` added together were greater than the total text length after using `AppendText`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use c# `Environment.NewLine` Property as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Or, the "old style" like `@"\r\n"`.

Rgds,